# Is there a way to run a windows mobile application on android?

Tags: android, windows, mobile

For example I have an application developed on windows mobile 5 and I want to run it on P1000 Galaxy Tab, is there a way to do it? Perhaps a vmware like?

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way. Any emulators are not ported to android yet.